# Override core-site.xml property value at spark-submit execution time

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

Is there a way to override core-site property value when executing spark submit?

I can use HADOOP_CONF_DIR variable in spark-env.sh to point to a new core-site file, but I only want to override few values to to use different storage accounts for each spark job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found answer to my own question.

hadoop-related configuration can be overridden by pre-fixing "spark.hadoop" to property key, then submit to sparkconf.

i.e.
spark-submit --sparkconf spark.hadoop.io.file.buffer.size 12952

See source code here: 
https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/b6cf1348170951396a6a5d8a65fb670382304f5b